# vue close page function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

подскажите как реализовать закрытие страницы (vue componenta) через функцию в vue js

по примеру настроен роутинг

```
{
path: '/example',
component: Layout,
redirect: '/example/list',
name: 'Example',
meta: {
  title: 'example',
  icon: 'example'
},
children: [
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: () => import('@/views/example/create'),
    name: 'CreateArticle',
    meta: { title: 'createArticle', icon: 'edit' }
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id(\\d+)',
    component: () => import('@/views/example/edit'),
    name: 'EditArticle',
    meta: { title: 'editArticle', noCache: true },
    hidden: true
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: () => import('@/views/example/list'),
    name: 'ArticleList',
    meta: { title: 'articleList', icon: 'list' }
  }
]
```

},

при переходе срабатывает компонент который находиться в store/moduls (ведет историю посещений TagsView)

```
const tagsView = {
    state: {
        visitedViews: [],
        cachedViews: []
      },
    mutations: {    
        DEL_VISITED_VIEWS: (state, view) => {
        for (const [i, v] of state.visitedViews.entries()) {
        if (v.path === view.path) {
        state.visitedViews.splice(i, 1)
        break
        }
    }
    for (const i of state.cachedViews) {
    if (i === view.name) {
        const index = state.cachedViews.indexOf(i)
        state.cachedViews.splice(index, 1)
        break
            }
        }
    }
},
  actions: {
      addVisitedViews({ commit }, view) {
      commit('ADD_VISITED_VIEWS', view)
    },
    delVisitedViews({ commit, state }, view) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            commit('DEL_VISITED_VIEWS', view)
            resolve([...state.visitedViews])
                })
            }   
        }
    }
}

export default tagsView
```

вопрос как вызвать, на странице где отправка создания/редактирования) формы submit, функцию самоудаления записи о текущей формы => по сути delVisitedViews

пример в картинке как это выглядит https://ibb.co/d3Ruee

например createArticle.vue имеет функцию submit() которая отправляет данные

```
submitForm(formName) {
    axios.post('....')  = данные отправлены
    this.$store.закрываем текущий компонент
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> после отправки формы в CreateArticle.vue, страница CreateArticle.vue
>   должна закрыться

Вам надо перейти после этого на страницу `ArticleList`? Тогда в компоненте можете написать:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'ArticleList' })
```

Или Вам надо закрыть вкладку браузера? Закрыть вкладку просто так не получиться, можете попробовать windwo.close(), но лучше открыть окно через [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) и потом вызвать на нем метод close().

> пробовал через destroy()

это удаляет компонент

Comment: мне надо закрыть компонент CreateArticle.vue и сделать переход на List, переход делается, а вот с закрытием проблема

Comment: Если перейти со страницы `CreateArticle` на `ArticleList`, то CreateArticle не должна показываться. У вас не так?!

Comment: после перехода CreateArticle остается в песочнице, и на нее можно вернуться - пример : https://ibb.co/cWe9ue

Comment: то есть у Вас там есть панелька которая показывает открытые страницы и после создания Вам нужно перейти на ArticleList, но чтобы в панельке осталось CreateArticle?

Comment: она остается, надо ее закрыть, это element ui vue

Comment: я не представляя как у вас там эта панелька устроенна, мне нужен код хотябы

Comment: исправил вопрос, дали немного пищи для размышления, однако все равно не доходит...

Comment: грубо говоря вместо кнопки Reset с картинки сделать закрытие

Comment: Вы вызывали? this.$store.dispatch('tagsView/delVisitedViews', ваш view) это же модуль? по идее у него такой путь

Comment: в этом и проблема не знаю что должно быть вместо, ваш view

Comment: Тобавляете через addVisitedViews Вы как, что туда передаете? Вы этот код случайно не скопировали у кого-то?

Comment: шаблон element-ui vue